# Connected spaces that remain connected after removing finitely many points

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness, dimension-theory-analysis

Suppose that $X$ is a connected compact Hausdorff space with the property that for every finite set $F\subseteq X$ the space $X\setminus F$ is connected. Can we conclude that the covering dimension of $X$ is at least 2? Note: I do not assume that $X$ is path-connected.

This question is somewhat dual to the classical problem of Menger whether adjoining finitely many points to a zero-dimensional space keeps the dimension 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Menger sponge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menger_sponge) is a counterexample. It is compact, Hausdorff, and of dimension 1, and the complement of any finite subset is path connected.

Answer (score 1):

The [Bucket-handle continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indecomposable_continuum) is a subset of the plane of dimension $1$, and has no finite separator.

The complement of any finite set is, however, very far from path-connected, in contrast to the Menger sponge.

I wonder if there is a set in the plane of dimension $1$ such that every co-finite subset is path-connected?

Comment: Of course: The Sierpinski carpet. Menger curve has a stronger non-separation property than the S.c.: Every subgraph of the Menger curve is non-separating, while S.c. contains a plenty of separating circles.

Comment: @MoisheCohen oh yes.  For some reason I was thinking the flat version of the Menger sponge is not connected.